# alert dialog in email validator

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

Hi i have a problem with create email validator. I ask you for a tips, because I have to create email validator with class AllertDialog.Builder, and if email is correct then dialog message is "Adress email is Correct" and button "ok" to return to main view, but if email is incorrect then message is "Adress email is incorrect" and button "save" and "clear", which means respectively save adress email in textview and clear adress in textview.
But I dont know how create a code in MainActivity, i was trying many times but always there were problems. Could someone write me step by step:

1) how correctly declare button and textview

2) how declare alertDialog Building and where

3) how create positive and negative button

Thanks

ps: I am noob ;)

Comment: You can not ask directly for a ready made code. You should search out and learn some basic android coding on your own, and after that if you get stuck anywhere, you should post a question with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Create xml file with following pattern below and name as dialog.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
....>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    ... />


<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="@string/yes"
    android:id="@+id/yes"
    .../>

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="@string/no"
    android:id="@+id/no"
    ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you need to write a java code to connect this dialog view you created in xml,

```
Dialog boxDialog= new Dialog(this);
boxDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        boxDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        boxDialog.setCancelable(false);

        Button yes = (Button) boxDialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        Button no = (Button) boxDialog.findViewById(R.id.no);
        //Connect TextView as well
        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do your code here
            }
        });
        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //Do your code here
            }
        });

boxDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I created something what is not working now, but this is not main problem. I would ask you  how correct my code and how check email validation by class, which is correctly.

This is my mainActivity

class MainActivity : Activity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override public void OnClick(View v){
            if(!EmailValidator) // check if address email is correct by class
            AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Address email is correct" )
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterfaceListener(){
                        @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

                            // return to main display
                        }

                        AlertDialog.alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    })

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Addres email is incorrect")
                    .setPositiveButton("save", null);
            .setNegativeButton("clear", newDialogInterfaceListener())
            @Override public void OnClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                // clear textview


        }

                   AlertDialog.alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            )
        }


    })
```

}
}

and this is my emailValidator
package com.daftmobile.a4bhomework1

import java.util.regex.Pattern

object EmailValidator {
    private val pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}")

```
fun isValidEmail(email: String) = pattern.matcher(email).matches()
```

}

I would be very grateful for little help.